# How to fix openCVcamera in Android(rgba,bgra)

Tags: android, opencv

Hi I'm using opencvCamera in my Android project.
when I use opencvCamera, preview is bluish at android emulator.
but!! in my Physical device, there is no problem. How can I fix it? please help me!!
my English is so bad. sorry...
here's my code:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    matInput = inputFrame.rgba();


    if ( matResult == null )
        matResult = new Mat(matInput.rows(), matInput.cols(), matInput.type());


    matResult = matInput.clone();


    return matResult;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at opencv's cvtColor function with code RGBA2BGRA

Comment: How can I find it??
when I use cvtColor(RGBA2BGRA), in emulator it is normal but
in physical device, it is bluish

Comment: if the colors are not swapped (bluish in total. not only red and blue swapped) then it might be a missing white balancing. find the lowest and highest r and g and b values and stretch the whole image pixel values so that the lowest bcomes [0,0,0] and the highest becomes [255,255,255]

Comment: you could also save a single image and load it with GIMP and test with the white balancing function of GIMP (colors->automatic->white-balacning).